# What does "%1$#" mean when used in String.format (Java)?

Tags: java, string, format, string-formatting

Language is Java. What does the `%1$#` mean in...

```
static String padright (String str, int num) {
   return String.format("%1$#" + num + "str", str);
}
```

In the Java API, `String.format()` is used in this way:

```
public static String format(String format, Object... args)
```

So I think `%1$#` is a format specifier.

`%[flags][width][.precision][argsize]typechar` is the template.

- 1 is a flag?
- $ is the width?
- # is the precision?
- num is the argsize?
- "str" is the typechar?

Is that right?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Template:

```
%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
```

> The optional argument_index is a
>   decimal integer indicating the
>   position of the argument in the
>   argument list. The first argument is
>   referenced by "1$", the second by
>   "2$", etc.
>
> The optional flags is a set of
>   characters that modify the output
>   format. The set of valid flags depends
>   on the conversion.
>
> The optional width is a decimal integer indicating the minimum
>   number of characters to be written to
>   the output.
>
> The optional precision is a
>   non-negative decimal integer usually
>   used to restrict the number of
>   characters. The specific behavior
>   depends on the conversion.
>
> The required conversion is a
>   character indicating how the argument
>   should be formatted. The set of valid
>   conversions for a given argument
>   depends on the argument's data type.

`%1$` refers to the first substitution. In this case the string `str`.
`#` is flag which says the result should use a conversion-dependent alternate form.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 2):

```
%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion

%1$s
```

% is mandatory for format
1$ is the first argument passed
2$ is the second... etc
s here is the string type conversion (result is obtained by invoking arg.toString())

Example with multiple string arguments:

```
String firstName = "John";
String lastName = "Doe";
String formattedString = String.format("My name is %1$s %2$s.", firstName, lastName);
System.out.println(formattedString);
```

Output:

```
My name is John Doe.
```

In this example, %1$s is used to reference the first string argument (firstName), and %2$s is used to reference the second string argument (lastName).

Example with multiple numeric arguments:

```
int num1 = 10;
double num2 = 3.14159;
String formattedString = String.format("The value of num1 is %1$d and the value of num2 is %2$.2f.", num1, num2);
System.out.println(formattedString);
```

Output:

```
The value of num1 is 10 and the value of num2 is 3.14.
```

In this example, %1$d is used to reference the first numeric argument (num1), and %2$.2f is used to reference the second numeric argument (num2) and format it as a floating-point value with two decimal places.

Example with mixed arguments:

```
String name = "John";
int age = 30;
double height = 1.80;
String formattedString = String.format("%1$s is %2$d years old and is %3$.2f meters tall.", name, age, height);
System.out.println(formattedString);
```

Output:

```
John is 30 years old and is 1.80 meters tall.
```

In this example, %1$s is used to reference the first string argument (name), %2$d is used to reference the second numeric argument (age), and %3$.2f is used to reference the third numeric argument (height) and format it as a floating-point value with two decimal places.