# How to use String.format() in java

Tags: java, string-formatting

I want to create a string in java with a prefix Size like this

```
String x = "PIPPO                "; //21 character
```

How can I obtain a string with a prefix size and the other character is space?

I have build this code but I have an error

```
String ragioneSociale =String.format("%21c%n", myString);
```

Comment: It'd be useful if you read the Formatter documentation and mention what error you get

Comment: @CraigR8806 Because it is bad practice to re-invent the wheel when the standard APIs already implement a generic, well-tested, robust solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can right pad your String ?

```
String x = "PIPPO";
String xRightPadded = String.format("%1$-21s", x);
```

more informations can be found here : [How can I pad a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java)

Comment: I was too lazy to check the padding part of the format; so my vote goes to your quick answer on that!

Comment: Can you explain what `%1$` means? At least a Minium of Explanation will be helpful

Comment: @Jens : you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762836/what-does-1-mean-when-used-in-string-format-java , this is the argument_index

Answer (score 1):

Message you get is

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: c != java.lang.String

Because "c" is the format specification for character.

You have to use "s" because you want a string:

```
String ragioneSociale =String.format("%-21s%n", myString);
```

And because you want it left aligned, you have to add a minus sign.

For more informations see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) of Formatter.

Comment: Same thought; you were a bit quicker here ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
String ragioneSociale =String.format("%21c%n", myString);
```

The `c` is the wrong format specifier. You want: `s` instead. From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html):

> 's', 'S'  general If the argument arg is null, then the result is "null". If arg implements Formattable, then arg.formatTo is invoked. Otherwise, the result is obtained by invoking arg.toString().
>
> 'c', 'C'  character   The result is a Unicode character

And as the argument you are providing is a **String**, not a character `c` can't work.

And for the aligning with spaces; go for "%1$-21s" as format instead.

Comment: I have used your code and I have change c whit s, but now I have this "                 PIPPO" intead I want the the blank space is after string

Comment: See my updated answer; or the other one that gave you the correct pattern as well.